# NAS storage problem

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage

Im running a small program on Buffalo NAS, which is being accessed by several users through network share. Recently the program started to crash quite often and kicks out the user while they work on it. 
My question: Does concurrent users accessing same file via network share on NAS will affect program stability or NAS doesn't support more users accessing the same share with different logins?

Answer (score 0):

Which Buffalo NAS are you using? It's probably not meant for a multi-user, high-performance environment. That being said, could your program be installed on each workstation, but store its data on the NAS? That change may alleviate the load on the NAS.

Comment: Model Number: TS-RVH8.0TL/R6EU
Buffalo Terastation 3 Pro

Program : Written in Delphi, Actually Program is stored on the NAS and is accessed by the users. Basically the users edit and modify the file.

Answer (score 0):

No, the concurrent access should not have any impact on your program stability: the binary is loaded by the OS in memory and executed from there. Your application make use of that NAS resources/shares? because the service supporting the resource can exaust all the memory and crash (or killed by the kernel). Also you should consider the case of virus problem (file infector).

Comment: Process Hacker tells me the resource used up by the memory and I cant find anything exceeding normal memory usage, not don't know how to sort out if there is virus. NAS was never connected to online.